# Return JSON array with postgres functions

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I'm new to Postgres functions.
I'm trying to return part of JSON response similar to:

```
"ids":[
        
          "9f076580-b5f5-4e73-af08-54d5fc4b87c0",
          "bd34cfad-53c7-4443-bf48-280e34d76881"
           
       ]
```

This ids is stored in table unit and I query them as a part of subquery and then transform into JSON with the next query

```
SELECT coalesce(json_agg(row_to_json(wgc)), '[]'::json)
FROM (
         SELECT
            (
                SELECT COALESCE(json_agg(row_to_json(ids)), '[]'::json)
                FROM (SELECT json_agg(l.ids) as "id"
                      FROM unit
                     ) as ids
            )  as "ids",
             ......
         FROM companies c
               
 ) AS wgc;
```

The problem is that this query gives me extract object which I want to omit.
"ids":[
{
"id":[
"9f076580-b5f5-4e73-af08-54d5fc4b87c0",
"bd34cfad-53c7-4443-bf48-280e34d76881"
]
}
]

How can omit this "id" object??

Comment: What is `l`?  Your query is incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard to tell how your table looks like, but something like this should work:

```
select jsonb_build_object('ids', coalesce(jsonb_agg(id), '[]'::jsonb))
from unit
```

---

I think you are overcomplicating things. You only need a single nesting level to get the IDs as an array. There is no need to use `row_to_json` on the array of IDs. The outer `row_to_json()` will properly take care of that.

```
SELECT coalesce(json_agg(row_to_json(wgc)), '[]'::json)
FROM (
  SELECT (SELECT json_agg(l.ids) FROM unit ) as ids
         .... 
  FROM companies c
) AS wgc;
```

The fact that the `select ... from unit` is not a co-related sub-query is a bit suspicious though. This means you will get the same array for each row in the `companies` table. I would have expected something like `(select .. from unit u where u.??? = c.???) as ids`

Comment: you are right. Found a solution  SELECT coalesce(json_agg(row_to_json(wgc)), '[]'::json)
FROM (
         SELECT
            (
                SELECT COALESCE(json_agg( ids), ..... Basically one level was redundant

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand your question.  This code:

```
SELECT (
            SELECT COALESCE(json_agg(row_to_json(ids)), '[]'::json)
            FROM (SELECT json_agg(l.ids) as "id"
                  FROM unit l
                 ) as ids
        )  as "ids"
```

Returns:

```
[{"id":["9f076580-b5f5-4e73-af08-54d5fc4b87c0", "bd34cfad-53c7-4443-bf48-280e34d76881as"]}]
```

which seems to be what you want.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=590ce2be364458e0b1f30b2c84620459) is a db<>fiddle.

Something else in your query is returning a JSON object that has `ids` as a field.  You seem to want to construct the object you want.

Comment: updated a little bit. Sorry I can't a post a real code a the whole query. Thanks for your help. Basically it is nested select inside another inside postgres function.